# Sticky Footer floating in page when resizing (reasked)

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

This question was posted a few years ago [By Sally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786483/sticky-footer-floating-in-the-page-when-resizing) but she solved it herself and her solution is not working for me.

I have gone through practically all of the relevant sticky footer pages on this site and a bunch from other places but I cannot find anything answering this question. I am sure it has to do with my layout but I have tried every way I have researched and can think of and this is the closest I could get to a sticky footer I am happy with.

Here is the HTML I am working with.

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header class="main-header">
            <a href="index.html"> <img src="logo3.png" alt="logo" /> </a>
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a id="home" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="second-nav">
                <li><a id="about" href="About.html">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li><a id="portfolio" href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="SportsComplex.html">Sports Complex</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </header>

        <body class="body">
            <div class="frameT">
                <div class="frameTC">
                    <div class="thumb" id="thumbs">
                        <a id="single_image1" href=".html"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" />
                            <span class="caption">_______</span>
                        </a>
                        <a id="single_image1" href=".html"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" />
                            <span class="caption">________</span>
                        </a>
                        <a id="single_image1" href=".html"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" />
                            <span class="caption">________</span>
                        </a>
                        <span class="stretch"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>

        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="quote">
                <h6>""</h6>
                <p> - </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the CSS

```
/*header*/
.main-header {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1%;
    width: 98%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 904px;
    z-index: 10;
    border: 0px solid #2675a9;
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: #606060;
    background-color: rgb(29, 67, 129);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 5px black;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 5px black;
    box-shadow:0 1px 5px black;
}

.main-header:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.main-header li {
    display: inline;
}

.main-header img {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 5.5px;
    left: 5.5px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}

.main-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 12.5px 0 12.5px 5px;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-nav a {
    text-shadow: 0.06em 0.08em #2666b1;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    color: #ebebeb;
    font-family: StonyIsland;
    display: block;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.logo {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10.5px;
    margin: 0;
}

.second-nav {
    float: right;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    border: none;
    padding: 9.5px;
}

.second-nav > li {
    float: left;
    border: solid 1px #ebebeb;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
}

.second-nav li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.second-nav li:second-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.second-nav a {
    color: #ebebeb;
    display: block;
    font-family: Capsuula;
    font-size: 1.13em;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
    text-shadow: none;
    color: rgb(237, 12, 12);
}

/*body*/
html {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;   
}

#main {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 60px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

/*body location*/

 #thumbs {   
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}

#thumbs a {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    margin-top: 12%;
}

#thumbs img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 60px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 20px black;
}

.caption {
    display: block;
}

/*footer*/

footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255) transparent;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.footer .quote {
    float: right;
    color: rgb(56, 56, 56);
}

.footer h6 {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Capsuula;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px;
}

.footer p {
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: Capsuula;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding;
    5px;
    padding-right: 12px;
}
```

Here is my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfr0d0zL/)

In my normal full screen the three 300px x 300px squares fit in a line and everything is well and good but when the window size is reduced (like the one in my fiddle) the squares turn into two lines and are pushed off the screen. The footer stays in place at the bottom of the screen until you scroll then it just stays put and does not follow the bottom of the page.

I would like the footer to either get pushed to the bottom of the screen when the squares get forced into two lines.

-or-

Stay at the bottom of the screen and scroll with the user.

Any help would be very much appreciate!

Comment: You have two `body`s — one inside the other. Not sure if this has anything to do with your problem, but it's invalid.

Comment: Have you tried setting `position: fixed` on `.footer`? Or set `position: relative` on `#container`? It's a little unclear what you're asking for, but I think those might do what you want.

Comment: I had tried the fixed before but it was not working as intended. However after fixing the body issue it is now working. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the excess body and turned it into a div. I ended the container before the footer and added a `push div`, equal in height to the `footer`. Seems to work now. Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfr0d0zL/1/)

```css
/*header*/
 .main-header {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1%;
    width: 98%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 904px;
    z-index: 10;
    border: 0px solid #2675a9;
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: #606060;
    background-color: rgb(29, 67, 129);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 5px black;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 5px black;
    box-shadow:0 1px 5px black;
}
.main-header:after {
    content:" ";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.main-header li {
    display: inline;
}
.main-header img {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 5.5px;
    left: 5.5px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
.main-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 12.5px 0 12.5px 5px;
    padding: 0;
}
.main-nav a {
    text-shadow: 0.06em 0.08em #2666b1;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    color: #ebebeb;
    font-family: StonyIsland;
    display: block;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.logo {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10.5px;
    margin: 0;
}
.second-nav {
    float: right;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    border: none;
    padding: 9.5px;
}
.second-nav > li {
    float: left;
    border: solid 1px #ebebeb;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
}
.second-nav li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
.second-nav li:second-child {
    border-left: none;
}
.second-nav a {
    color: #ebebeb;
    display: block;
    font-family: Capsuula;
    font-size: 1.13em;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: rgb(237, 12, 12);
}
/*body*/
 html {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
}
#main {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 60px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
/*body location*/
 #thumbs {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}
#thumbs a {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    margin-top: 12%;
}
#thumbs img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 60px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 20px black;
}
.caption {
    display: block;
}
/*footer*/
.push{height:60px;}
 footer {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255) transparent;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
footer .quote {
    float: right;
    color: rgb(56, 56, 56);
}
footer h6 {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Capsuula;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px;
}
footer p {
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: Capsuula;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding;
    5px;
    padding-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header class="main-header"> <a href="index.html"> <img src="logo3.png" alt="logo" /> </a>

            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a id="home" href="index.html">Home</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="second-nav">
                <li><a id="about" href="About.html">About Us</a>

                </li>
                <li><a id="portfolio" href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="SportsComplex.html">Sports Complex</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <div class="body">
            <div class="frameT">
                <div class="frameTC">
                    <div class="thumb" id="thumbs"> <a id="single_image1" href=".html"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" />
                            <span class="caption">_______</span>
                        </a>
 <a id="single_image1" href=".html"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" />
                            <span class="caption">________</span>
                        </a>
 <a id="single_image1" href=".html"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" />
                            <span class="caption">________</span>
                        </a>
 <span class="stretch"></span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="quote">
                 <h6>"Hello"</h6>

                <p>-</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: this way it will always stay at the bottom of the screen

Comment: if you want the footer to be always visible then just use position fixed and remove the push div http://jsfiddle.net/sfr0d0zL/3/

Comment: I guess in the end it was the two body elements that was throwing me off. The fixed position was not working as I wanted it before but after it works perfectly! I couldn't get the push technique to work but that is fine I like the fixed more. Thank you for your help!

Comment: For the fixed to work you need to add a margin-bottom to the content div. Equal to the height of the push. Then it will work. I forgot that. Upvote and get a badge ;)